# Is there a way to make WolframScript give outputs as a single line?

Tags: output-formatting, scripting

When the output of a calculation includes exponents or fractions, WolframScript is writing them out on separate lines (exponents one line above, then a line with the rest of the numerator, then a line of hyphens for the fraction bar, then the denominator) instead of within one line (exponents in-line using a carat [^], fractions in-line using a slash [/]). Can I change that behavior?

For example, I currently get this output:

```
                                    2                                                                     2
        -(E (E + F) (2 E + F + G) (F  + 5 E (E + F) + 2 E G + F G)) + A B ((A + B) (A + B - 4 E - 2 F - G)  + A B (-A - B + 4 E + 2 F + G) + 12 C D (-A - B + C + D + 4 E + 2 F + G))
Out[1]= -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                             12
```

But I'd much prefer to get it formatted like this:

```
Out[1]= (-(E (E + F) (2 E + F + G) (F^2 + 5 E (E + F) + 2 E G + F G)) + A B ((A + B) (A + B - 4 E - 2 F - G)^2 + A B (-A - B + 4 E + 2 F + G) + 12 C D (-A - B + C + D + 4 E + 2 F + G)))/12
```

I am using `Wolfram Language 13.2.0 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)` in the command-line interface that comes up when launching wolframscript.exe.

UPDATE

Here is the complete input and output from the things suggested in the comments:

```
In[2]:= FullSimplify[(A*B*((A + B)*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G))^2 - A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) - 12*C*D*(A + B - C - D - (4*E + 2*F + G))) - E*(E + F)*(2*E + F + G)*(5*E*(E + F) + 2*E*G + F^2 + F*G))/12, A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) + E + F)*(2*E + F + G) == 0]//InputForm                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Syntax::sntxf: "F) + 2*E*G + F^2 + F*G))/12, A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) + E + F" cannot be followed by ")*(2*E + F + G) == 0]//InputForm".


In[3]:= FullSimplify[(A*B*((A + B)*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G))^2 - A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) - 12*C*D*(A + B - C - D - (4*E + 2*F + G))) - E*(E + F)*(2*E + F + G)*(5*E*(E + F) + 2*E*G + F^2 + F*G))/12, A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) + E + F)*(2*E + F + G) == 0] //InputForm                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Syntax::sntxf: "F) + 2*E*G + F^2 + F*G))/12, A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) + E + F" cannot be followed by ")*(2*E + F + G) == 0] //InputForm".


In[4]:= Expand[(1+x)^3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                     2    3
Out[4]= 1 + 3 x + 3 x  + x

In[5]:= InputForm[FullSimplify[(A*B*((A + B)*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G))^2 - A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) - 12*C*D*(A + B - C - D - (4*E + 2*F + G))) - E*(E + F)*(2*E + F + G)*(5*E*(E + F) + 2*E*G + F^2 + F*G))/12, A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) + E + F)*(2*E + F + G) == 0]]                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Syntax::sntxf: "F) + 2*E*G + F^2 + F*G))/12, A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) + E + F" cannot be followed by ")*(2*E + F + G) == 0]]".
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing?  From the command line  input: `wolframscript -code "Expand[(1+x)^3]"` I get the output: `1 + 3*x + 3*x^2 + x^3`

Comment: @DanielHuber the exact input I used to generate the example was `FullSimplify[(A*B*((A + B)*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G))^2 - A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) - 12*C*D*(A + B - C - D - (4*E + 2*F + G))) - E*(E + F)*(2*E + F + G)*(5*E*(E + F) + 2*E*G + F^2 + F*G))/12, A*B*(A + B - (4*E + 2*F + G)) + E + F)*(2*E + F + G) == 0]`, the most recent thing I'd tried; but all my inputs are producing this type of out-of-line output.

Comment: @DanielHuber I tried inputting `Expand[(1+x)^3]` and got this:

`|                     2    3`

`|Out[4]= 1 + 3 x + 3 x  + x`

Comment: @Bill I tried adding `//InputForm` to the end of the input and also wrapping the input in `InputForm[...]`, and both result in a `Syntax::sntxf` error.

Comment: Could it be that the problem comes from your CMD line terminal. I am using the built in terminal of Windows 10.

Comment: @Lawton, are you sure you typed in everything correctly? Please show us the whole syntax error (there is usually an explanation of where the error is). Did you use correct forward slashes (//) not backward ones (\\\)? Take a look at [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIDqb.png).

Comment: @Domen I edited the question with the complete inputs and outputs copied directly from the terminal.

Comment: @DanielHuber I am using the terminal that appears when launching wolframscript.exe on Windows 10.

Comment: @Lawton, the error message tells you what is wrong: you have unbalanced parentheses. It is perhaps [easier to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWYB9.png) in Mathematica (look at purple parentheses). Either one opening parentheses is missing somewhere in the beginning, or the one after `F` should not be there.

Comment: @Domen Ah, apparently an opening parenthesis got dropped when I entered that line the first time and stayed lost when I copied that first entry into later entries. Adding it back in removes the error and gives an output in the form I want. Is there any way to make InputForm the default output, or do I need to add that to the end of every input?

Comment: You can use [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html), such as `$PrePrint = InputForm;` – this will make all output be in `InputForm`.

Comment: @Domen That works. If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`InputForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html):

```
In[1]:= (a + b)/2

        a + b
Out[1]= -----
          2

In[2]:= (a + b)/2 // InputForm   
                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[2]//InputForm= (a + b)/2
```

To automatically put all output expressions in their `InputForm`, use [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html):

```
$PrePrint = InputForm;
```

Evaluate it once at the beginning of your session, or put it in [`init.m`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) for automatic initialization. To remove the setting, use `$PrePrint =.`.